# Django get data from related model which has the FK

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

how can i make this queryset:

```sql
SELECT 
  p.*,
  o.name,
  o.link
FROM property p
INNER JOIN listing l on l.property_id = p.id
INNER JOIN ota o on o.id = l.ota_id
```

models

```py
class Property(Model):
   code = CharField()
   ...

class Listing(Model):
   ota = ForeignKey(Ota)
   property = ForeignKey(Property)

class Ota(Model):
   name = Charfield()
   link = Charfield()
```

with `Property.objects.all()` I can see in the returned object that there is a `listing_set`

let say:

```py
queryset = Property.objects.all()
queryset[0].listing_set.all()
```

but it brings the entire model, and not the related to property_id;

also tried to get Ota data in serializer with `SerializerMethodField` and perform a new query to get this info, but decrease performance significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use **related_name**

[related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

```
class Property(Model):
   code = CharField()
   ...

class Listing(Model):
   ota = ForeignKey(Ota)
   property = ForeignKey(Property,related_name='listinings')

class Ota(Model):
   name = Charfield()
   link = Charfield()
```

and

```
pp=Property.objects.first()
pp.listinings.all()
```